# How do I set a timer in Ogre 3D?

Tags: timer, countdown, ogre, ogre3d, seconds

I want to be able to call a function every 5 seconds but I dont how to do this. I read about the Timer class in ogre3d but I dont understand how I would use that since there is not much information about it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=TimerManager) may help you. That was a second result in Google, to be honest.